# How can i show video in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player

I want to show video from server into my application, for this I want use `VideoView` in android.
I want first show video thumbnail (image) , when click on play button get request from server and it loads video show video, also show video time line in seekbar.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MediaController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html) and [ThumbnailUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html)